# canal Vs channel

Tags: word-usage

I'm always confused between **canal** and **channel** after I see that different teachers refer to the same thing with two different variants: canal and channel. Are indeed both (canal and channel) used for the same thing in the correct English?

Answer (score 4):

While *channel* and *canal* have the same origin, and have meanings in the same area, in ordinary English, they are quite separate, and it would be rare for them to be interchangeable.

*Channel* is a general word for a place where water or other fluids can pass: it is also used metaphorically, as in *channel of communication*.

*Canal*, apart from some specialised medical uses, only means an articial waterway originally built for boats or ships. We wouldn't normally use the word for an irrigation trench, for example.

Comment: What about anatomy descriptions? (we have some canals / channels in our body)

Comment: I said, **apart from some specialise medical uses**. Those are specific cases where "canal" is part of a set phrase, such as "alimentary canal". If it's not a thing where "canal" is in its name, it isn't called a canal.

Comment: and that means that in anatomy the term canal is the correct one? Sorry, it's not clear to me.

Comment: Expanding on @ColinFine 's comment,  _Canal_ (from Latin _canalis_) has many specific uses in medicine and anatomy, e.g. _alimentary canal, anterior semicircular canal, ulnar canal_ whereas _channel_ in medicine is found mainly in terms descriptive of biochemical processes like _calcium channel blocker_ and _ion channel._

Comment: By the way, I suspect that those teachers who "refer to the same thing with two different variants: canal and channel" are not native English speakers. In English, the two terms are _not_ synonymous. It is common for native speakers of French and Spanish, for example, to imagine that _canal_ and _channel_ are synonymous in English because in both French and Spanish, _canal_ means "channel."

Comment: I don't believe so, @Assiduous. I'm not an anatomist, but as far as I am aware there are several specific organs which have "canal" in their name, such as the alimentary canal (more general than one organ) and the semicircular canals in the ear. For those specific items, the word "canal" is used and no other word. For anything else in anatomy, the word "canal" is not used - but nor is "channel": "duct" or "tube" are the common words.